# Javascript Unix Timestamp Conversion

Tags: javascript

I have a plugin that I am using that requires the date that is selected to be passed as a unix timestamp as it allows you to drill down.

The issue I am having is that the UNIX timestamp its creating is constricted to a certain time period as well so when I run my query, its only getting me things in between the time specified. (I understand that's what a timestamp is).

I am generating the timestamp as follows:

```
function myDate(input) {
 var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
 input = input.split('-');
 input[1] = months.indexOf(input[1]);
 return new Date(+input[2], +input[1], +input[0])
}     

var startDate = myDate('01-Apr-2015')
startDate = startDate.getTime() / 1000.0;

alert(startDate)
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/rnho8k3s/

My goal / end result is to have the timestamp span the whole day `1428019200` through `1428105599000` which is April 3, 2015 00:00:00 - April 3, 2015 23:59:59

How can I go about achieving this instead of it creating the timestamp from the current point in time?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. What do you mean "have the timestamp span the whole day". A timestamp is a point in time, not a time span. Do you want two timestamps representing the start and the end of the day?

Comment: I pass it a day (April 3, 2015) I want to get the timestamp for that date (not the current time) but the very beginning of the day `00:00:00`. I want to also be able to get the end of a day `23:59:59`. That would give me the timestamp that spans the whole day

Comment: In the end, I will be able to say "Start Date is April 3, 2015 and the End Date is April 5th, 2015. In my query, I want everything in between that which would be April 3, 2015 00:00:00 through April 15, 2015 23:59:59.

Comment: You can use a query like this: `date >= Start Date AND date < End Date + 1 day`

Comment: Beginning and end of day at what timezone? The client's? UTC?

Comment: UTC is how I store the information so that would be fine

Comment: Which server-side language do you use?

Comment: SQL Server for the database, using Javascript to create the timestamp from a date field.

Comment: I also use js to submit `start-timeStamp`, `end-timeStamp`. On server-side i will convert these timestamps to `DateTime` objects and put them in query: `date >= Start Date AND date < EndDatePlus1` to get all records between `Start Date` and `End Date`

Comment: Adding an extra day to something isn't solving my issue though. If my timestamp is April 3, 2015 at 15:15:00 and I add 1 day to that, its giving me data on the 4th that I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

I built something like this for PHP, I called it a "DateFrame".

Basically, you'll have to capture the dates you want, append the begining (00:00:00) and ending (23:59:59) timestamps and use Javascripts Date class to generate the timestamps.

Maybe it can help.

https://github.com/dmgig/DateFrame

```
public function __construct($start, $end, $field = null){
    $this->start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start)) . ' 00:00:00';
    $this->end   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end))   . ' 23:59:59';

    $startdiff   = new DateTime($this->start);
    $enddiff     = new DateTime($this->end);
    $this->diff  = $enddiff->diff($startdiff)->format('%a');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the two UTC moments for the beginning and end of a day, you can use the following.

```
//                   Yr   Nov  1st
var begin = Date.UTC(2012, 11, 0);
//                  ms    sec  min  hour
var end = begin + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) - 1;
```

Comment: Is there a plugin that this needs to be used with? I get the following error: `TypeError: Date.UTC(...).getTime is not a function`

Comment: @SBB Sorry, there's no need to for `getTime()` [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) already returns the time stamp. Also, for a unix timestamp, you have to multiply them by 1000 since JavaScript uses milliseconds.